# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare __() (previously declared in D:\wamp\apps\phpMyAdmin\libraries\sql-parser\src\common.php:17)

Tags: phpmyadmin

I was working with PMA as always but today PMA freezes when I tried a simple request.
So I tried to reload the browser (Chrome), but now I can't access anymore to PMA due to the following error :

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare __() (previously declared in D:\wamp\apps\phpMyAdmin\libraries\sql-parser\src\common.php:17) in D:\wamp\apps\phpMyAdmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on line 290
```

Then after I have erased all cookies, I met this error :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function PMA\libraries\PMA_langSet() in D:\wamp\apps\phpMyAdmin\libraries\Config.php on line 1021
```

I tried to force to reload too, tried to download again PMA from the official website and to replace files in PMA's directory but the the error is still here.

I don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Delete all session cookies seems to correct the error.
Hope it helps.